# javascript getElementbyId for Paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm fairly new to scripting and using Javascript, but I'm trying to make a chrome extension which has to be able to read a string which is constantly generated by a web-app. I'm trying to use the `document.getElementById()` function, but the console only returns `undefined`.

```
function pkmnFunction() {
    var pokeString = document.getElementById("pkmnappear").innerHTML;
        console.log(pokeString);
}
```

Since this obviously isn't working properly, how would one go about retrieving such a string, then?

The Chrome Developer mode output, User interface and source code, with the wanted text field in the paragraph:

[image]

Comment: Did you forget calling the function? See, it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/7v1tvho9/

Comment: what's the HTML in question, and when does this function run?

Comment: please put all relevant code in this question instead of links

Comment: I've initially tried running the script in the chrome console, and am now trying to execute it via a <script src> from the popup.html


The thing is that the code can't be run in-line in the browser extension because of the new Chrome security feature-stuff, apparently.